# Cert-Manager JKS Keystores File Path for Spinnaker SSL Config

Tags: kubernetes, spinnaker, cert-manager, spinnaker-halyard

I am trying to create a certificate with `JKS keystore` using `cert-manager` inside my `kubernetes` cluster for `spinnaker` to refer to from its `ssl` configuration.

According to the [cert-manager documentation](https://cert-manager.io/docs/release-notes/release-notes-0.15/#general-availability-of-jks-and-pkcs-12-keystores), it states that `For JKS this adds the files: keystore.jks and truststore.jks to the target spec.secretName`

However, I cannot seem to find the actual path that jks files are created. My `spec.secretName` is set to `mtlscerts-jks`. What should be the path for the `keystore` for `spinnaker ssl configuration`?

I've also tried creating a `kubernetes` `volume` as below but still no file is found from the path.

```
kubernetes = {
      volumes = [
        {
          id        = "mtlscerts-jks"
          mountPath = "/etc/ssl/cert"
          type      = "secret"
          readOnly  = "true"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Update:
I've tried folloing steps from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57387364/spinnaker-setup-on-private-kubernetes-cluster-clouddriver-cert-error?rq=1) but still no file is found

```
com.netflix.spinnaker.halyard.core.error.v1.HalException: Failed to backup user file: /etc/ssl/certs/java/keystore.jks

...

Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /etc/ssl/certs/java/keystore.jks
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that there was a problem with issuing a certificate. After resolving this issue, I am able to see the `.jks` files